# Reassign value from json key/value pair to next key

Tags: php, arrays, json

I got a json file which looks like the following (Showing one out of several rows that looks the same):

```
 "description 1": {
  "year0": "49",
  "year1": "48",
  "year2": "876786",
  "year3": "1234"
},
```

Using PHP, I need to move each value down so value for year0 becomes the value for year1 and so on (value for year 3 will be removed and year0 will be empty like this:

```
 "description 1": {
  "year0": "",
  "year1": "49",
  "year2": "48",
  "year3": "876786"
},
```

Is there any faster way to process the data than looping through each key value, saving it to a variable and assigning it to the next key and so on?

Comment: There's probably a faster way. What have you tried? P.S. your question has nothing to do with `laravel` tag.

Comment: There's no magic array function to do what you want.  Even if there were, the function would still be iterating through the loop, not saving you any time.

Comment: Concerning your question, you need to understand that you don't modify JSON. It is only used for storage and transport. If you want to modify the data, you first have to parse the JSON in order to get the data to a modifyable form.

Comment: @Latheesan Reason for adding the laravel tag is that I'm using the laravel framework if there was a laravel-syntax way to do it. Removing the tag to not confuse anyone!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes, I just thought it was easier to show it in json, but of course I would decode it before modifying it.

Comment: Update: The way I did the array in the first place was stupid anyway and I changed it to be like the following:  description 1": { "", "49" ... } and then prepend an empty value as the first value and remove the last value in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no approach to do this faster, but i think there is a simple and readable approach, i think the best way to go about it is the collection method `mapWithKeys()`. It allows you to do an array map, but changing the key in the process. This will be easier in my opinion, instead of thinking of moving each variable down one place, just add one year to the key and remember to add the first year to the new array.

```
$years = collect(json_decode('json')->description_1);

$firstYear = null;

$years = $years->mapWithKeys(function ($value, $key) use (&$firstYear) {
    if (! $firstYear) {
        $firstYear = $key;
    }

    $year = intval(Str::after('year', $key)) + 1;

    return ['year' . $year => $value];
})->all();

$years[$firstYear] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` with `filter_var`

```
$a = json_decode($json, true);
$r = [];
foreach($a['description 1'] as $k => $v){
    $index = (int) filter_var($k, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
    $r[$k] = ($index == 0) ? '' : $a['description 1']['year'.--$index];
}
```

Live example :- https://3v4l.org/AtoZs